# Template specialisation: member function with parameter different from T

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is it possible to implement something like what follows using template specialisation?

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T, bool a, bool b>
class Test
{
    T value;

public:
    Test() {}
    Test( const T& val ) : value( val ) {}

    void Set( const T& val ) { // [1]
        value = val;
    }

    void Set( const float val ) { // [2] To run just for T != float
        ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<int, true, true> test1;
    test1.Set( 1234 ); // Run [1]

    Test<float, true, true> test2;
    test2.Set( 1.234f ); // Run [1]

    Test<int, true, true> test3;
    test3.Set( 1.234f ); // Run [2]
}
```

Is there a syntax to specify that a member function is the one to be selected when `T` is different from `float`?

Comment: Just because I have this open in a different tab: https://foonathan.net/2016/12/conditionally-removing-functions/. Link-only answering this is not an option, but I assume there's a duplicate around somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement something like what follows using template specialisation?

Yes: specializing the full `class Test`: generic case, with "[2]", and `float` case, without it.

Otherwise I suppose you can use SFINAE to disable "[2]" when `T` is `float`

```
template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_same_v<U, float>> Set( const float val )
 { /* ... */ }
```

Or maybe also

```
template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_same_v<U, float> && true == std::is_same_v<U, T>>
      Set( const float val )
 { /* ... */ }
```

if you want to avoid that `Set()` is enabled, in `float` case, explicating the `U` template type.

Comment: It works! Question: why cannot I specify a return type for the function any longer?

Comment: Another question: what is the syntax to implement the function out of the class block?

Comment: @Pietro You would have to specify the return type as the second argument of `std::enable_if_t`. See the link I posted in the comments (and also see that link for why this isn't the preferred solution).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Which in my case would be: `std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_same_v<U, float>, void>`?

Comment: @Pietro Yes, but that's the default for `enable_if_t` already. Doesn't hurt to explicitly specify it though I guess.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - What about the syntax to implement the function out of the class block? Is there a kind of nested template structure?

Comment: @Pietro You need two `template<...>`, yes. You also need to repeat all the SFINAE stuff, and since it's a template it has to be in the header anyway. So I don't think you will really gain much from defining the function outside of the class, you'll just have to repeat all the signature stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A clean option would be to use (non-polymorphic) inheritance to do the specialization without repeating everything:

```
namespace detail
{
    template< typename T, bool a, bool b>
    class TestImplBase
    {
    protected:
        T value;

    public:
        TestImplBase() {}
        TestImplBase( const T& val ) : value( val ) {}

        void Set( const T& val ) { // [1]
            value = val;
        }
    };

    // General case
    template< typename T, bool a, bool b>
    class TestImpl : public TestImplBase<T, a, b>
    {
    public:
        using TestImplBase<T, a, b>::TestImplBase; // keep the same constructors
        using TestImplBase<T, a, b>::Set; // See comment by Jarod42

        // Has [1] as well.

        void Set( const float val ) { // [2] To run just for T != float
            //...
        }
    };

    // Specialization for T == float
    template<bool a, bool b>
    class TestImpl<float, a, b> : public TestImplBase<float, a, b>
    {
    public:
        using TestImplBase<float, a, b>::TestImplBase; // keep the same constructors

        // Only has [1], not [2].
    };
}

template< typename T, bool a, bool b>
using Test = detail::TestImpl<T, a, b>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zRieA2

This is a very general approach, possibly a bit too general for your case, but that's hard to say from this small piece of code.

Comment: Nearly, but you call wrong overload ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5670e4fb7f67d5)), as `[2]` hides `[1]`. You need `using TestImplBase<T, a, b>::Set` ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb460cbd760362ac))

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for spotting that! Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With C++20, it would be very simple:

`requires` allow to "discard" method:

```
template <typename T, bool a, bool b>
class Test
{
    T value;
public:
    Test() {}
    Test(const T& val) : value( val ) {}

    void Set(const T& val) { value = val; }

    void Set(float val) requires (!std::is_same<T, float>::value) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Else SFINAE is generally the way to remove the overload (but requires template function, so you have to make one of your method template).

Comment: Nice simplification.